# "ob_gzhandler" no mesmo servidor nem sempre suportado

Tags: php, codificação-de-conteúdo

No mesmo servidor de alojamento, algumas contas suportam [`ob_gzhandler`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-gzhandler.php) e enviam a página com compressão para o navegador:

```
/* Sending gz-encoded data to web browsers
 * that support compressed web pages
 */
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
```

Mas outras contas com o código em cima falham e despoletam o seguinte erro:

> #### Content Encoding erro
>
> A página que você está tentando abrir não pode ser exibida porque usa uma forma não suportada ou inválida de compactação.
> Entre em contato com os responsáveis pelo site para informá-los sobre este problema.

## Pergunta

Como discernir a causa do erro de codificação inválida?

<sup>Nota: A configuração do PHP para ambos os domínios está rigorosamente igual, tal como as diretivas do Apache.</sup>

Comment: O script que gera o erro também é exatamente o mesmo para todas as contas?

Comment: Talvez eu esteja falando besteira, será que realmente as configurações estão nos usuários de maneira correta? Quero dizer se o servidor for "virtual" talvez o acesso das configurações não estejam apontadas corretamente. Eu acho que um simples `phpinfo();` testado em cada servidor iria lhe fornecer as informações necessárias.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Isto foi das primeiras coisas a ser analisado. O resultado do `phpinfo()` é _igualzissimo_ para todos os alojamentos em causa. :)

Comment: @AndréRibeiro Não, o erro provém em todos os projetos do mesmo ficheiro responsável por debitar o web-site para o navegador. Mas de projeto para projeto esse ficheiro tem algumas diferenças dado a sua antiguidade.

Comment: @Zuul Dê uma olhada [nesta resposta no SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6403260/4443230). Acho que pode ser esse o seu problema.

Comment: No *Apache Environment* o que ele retorna em `HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING`? Por que se você tem certeza que ambos retornam algo como: `gzip, deflate, lzma, sdch` então eu irei supor que o problema é no script, vou supor uma coisa, ao subir o arquivo para outro servidor talvez o FTP tenha usado BINARY ao invés de ASCII, ou então você usou algum editor online que codificou o seu documento com **UTF8 com BOM** ao invés de **sem BOM**. É só teoria.

Answer (score 1):

Para o meu caso em particular, o problema estava na definição dos cabeçalhos da página, onde nos *scripts* com o problema de despoletarem o erro de "Content Encoding", os cabeçalhos estavam a ser definidos após a abertura do *buffer* de saída:

```
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");

$expires = 2678400;
header("Pragma: public");
header("Cache-Control: maxage=".$expires);
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+$expires) . ' GMT');
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
```

Para resolver, os cabeçalhos foram definidos em primeiro lugar, e o *buffer* de saída em segundo:

```
$expires = 2678400;
header("Pragma: public");
header("Cache-Control: maxage=".$expires);
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+$expires) . ' GMT');
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');

ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
```

Dado tratarem-se de projetos antigos (+4 anos), parece que alguma coisa mudou nas últimas versões do PHP e a declaração da abertura do *buffer* de saída já não pode vir antes dos cabeçalhos da página.

Comment: Também pode ser algo que "reescreve" os `headers` no `ob_gzhandler` conforme os recursos disponíveis na maquina (assim suponho eu) ou então realmente mudança de versão. Na maquina que ocorre o problema, você poderia informar a versão do PHP (incluido se é x86, x64, etc) :) Só queria testar, obrigado.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento `PHP Version 5.4.26` em `x86_64`.

Comment: Obrigado, testei em servidores semelhantes, não obtive o erro, como não consigo afirmar nada, pode ser realmente os `header`s que estavam reescrevendo o `ob_start(...);`, ao colocar o `ob_start` após fixou o problema deles +1